# Context Carry-over with Alexa Conversations not possible?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm new to developing skills for Alexa and I'm following the tutorial "Build Multi-turn Skills Tutorial with Alexa Conversations". I've completed the tutorial up to the module [Keep Track of the Conversation with Context Carry-over](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/get-deeper/tutorials-code-samples/build-multi-turn-skills-with-alexa-conversations/module-5). Everything works so far but in the section **"Replace Values with Slots"** under step **"r. Scroll down to the section that says Responses and select notifySuccess_getRecommendation_context_carry_over from the drop-down."** there is no section "Response templates" in the modal. If I leave it as is I get an Error in the dialog menu:

```
"getRecommendation" under "API to Invoke" requires the same Response for all API Success / API Failure Dialog Acts.
```

Where do I find the "Response template" section for Alexa Conversations?

Comment: Looks like it's still in Beta and not fully complete. The module seems to be hidden because if you go from Module 4 at the bottom of the page, you'll see `Module 5: Add a Second API to Your Dialog.` which is different even though the link is available in the `Wrap-up` section of the module page. I recommend to skip it for now until it is improved.

Answer (score 0):

The user interface and some of the validations changed since the tutorial was written. You no longer need to link the response template together with the API in that screen.

Your error is not related to the dropdown. Based on the error you're facing, it sounds like you have annotated your dialogs so that a given API (API_1) is not always assigned the same response template across the API_success turns. Try making sure there only one API success response assigned to each API in your skill.

TL/DR: The UI changed. 2 APIs can share 1 API Success response, but the inverse is not true. Check your skill for 1 API with 2+ responses assigned to 'API Success'.